# Windows Phone 7 - How to calculate call duration or termination

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm new to windows phone 7 development...

Can anyone please tell me how to calculate call duration? or how to get notification of incoming call? using silverlight or c#

is there any API's available..

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to get calls information or notifications of incoming calls on the current Windows Phone 7 SDK.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to access call information.

However if your app is running and a call comes in the [Obscured](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationframe.obscured%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) event will be triggered. You can then use a combination of the `Unobscured`, `NavigatedTo`, `Loaded` & `Activated` events to determine when the app has the focus again.

This won't give you the length of the call but rather then time between an event that may be a call (including incoming SMS, alarms, etc.) and the user returning fully to your app. This may be a good enough approximation, but it will depend on your needs.