# Windows 7.1 SDK - Timing a call

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I currently have a "dumbphone", but I'm trying to make an app that'll time and store the call duration of incoming calls for windows 7.1 ("7.5") phones, for the user scheduling purposes.

However, after extensive searching and googling, with topics like this one:
[Windows Phone 7 - How to calculate call duration or termination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5135601/windows-phone-7-how-to-calculate-call-duration-or-termination)
it seems that the Windows 7/7.1 SDK does not allow access to recognizing when a call is coming in. I've read about obscure and unobscure, but that this wouldn't be a good idea since it would start the timer anytime the UI hides the program, not just calls.

I've thought that maybe I could just pull the call duration or the start/end time from the call history, but windows 7 SDK doesn't support that either it seems.

So I decided to seek help. Is there a way to make this work? Is there some clever way to recognize when a call is incoming and stopped? Or some clever way to pull call times/durations? Or maybe a way to detect when the user presses that "accept incoming call" button? Or maybe a way to single out when a call is obscuring the UI?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Due to security reasons your application does not have any kind of accsess to call history ect. So you are in a sendbox and you don't know nothing about phone calls.

Comment: can you provide some links which state these security measures? im looking for this, too...

Answer (score 0):

From the Windows Phone SDK, there is no way to achieve this!

The only thing I can think of is that when a call comes, the current app gets notified that is now Obscured because a new screen is now on top of it (the caller ID screen), and will get notified when it gets back to focus.

But the truth is that this happens even if a SMS message notification pops on the screen and the user taps to read it, or some app gets a notification pushed...

Comment: I thought about using Obscure, but I don't know much about it. Is there a way to differentiate what event/app is doing the obscuring?