# How to get the total call duration in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How can I get the total call duration of a windows phone (incomming call and outgoing call) ?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/q/5135601/1063254

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, There is no way to get the call related information in windows phone as of now.